# In postgresql, after importing the csv file, the serial number is not synchronized

Tags: database, postgresql, auto-increment, serial-number

I moved the existing MSSQL data to postgreSQL.

I imported / exported the csv file during this process.

And the serial number entered data sequentially.

The serial number did not work properly afterwards when I put the new value in the application.

As you can see, the sequence in postgresql is still fixed at 1.

I wonder why it's not syncing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem Statement

In your case, it sounds like the issue you're experiencing is that you've done the following:

1. Exported data which already has a serial number
2. Imported the export into a Postgres database
3. Tried to insert additional data, finding that the serial number either:
   a) generated a conflict because it tried to insert a duplicate of an existing serial number; or
   b) successfully inserted a duplicate of an existing serial number

## Background on Serials in Postgres

In PostgreSQL, the `serial` data type is really short-hand for an `integer` column with an associated `sequence` which controls the default behavior for the column.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases).

You can verify that behavior by examining the default value for the column (e.g. by using `\d+` in psql). The `Default` column should look something like: `nextval('schema.id_seq'::regclass)`. It's worth highlighting from the documentation that:

> In most cases you would also want to attach a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint to prevent duplicate values from being inserted by accident, but this is not automatic.

As a side note, it's important to note that sequences [**do not** promise that values will be consecutive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6224274/6591849).

## Solution

The reason why it's possible to end up in the situation you've described is that the sequence which generates new values is **only called when the value is not explicitly provided.**

When you think about `serial`s as integers and defaults, this starts to make more sense. The way that Postgres is tracking which value it should use next is through the sequence, and **it is only assigning new values from the sequence when you don't explicitly provide a value.**

The way to solve for this is to set the `nextval` using the [`setval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) function in Postgres. There are many different strategies for exactly how to do this, depending on whether you want to:

- Reset all of the serial numbers

  - [Example from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/244243/6591849)
  - [Another Example](https://fle.github.io/reset-a-postgresql-sequence-and-recompute-column-values.html)
- Keep all of the existing serial numbers and start from the next value
- Some other, custom solution

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389891/6591849) to the related question of how to set the sequence to a specific value.

### A Trivial Example

The example below shows how providing an explicit value to the insert/upload does **not** use the default/sequence, and how the next insert that does will continue along the existing sequence.

```
CREATE TABLE test (id serial, sample integer);
INSERT INTO test (sample) VALUES (101); -- assigns default, next value from id_seq (1)
INSERT INTO test (id, sample) VALUES (3, 102); -- assigns explicit value (3)
INSERT INTO test (sample) VALUES (103); -- assigns default, next value from id_seq (2)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you import csv file via copy command, you must set the value to the sequence with with sequences functions::
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-sequence.html

```
SELECT setval('seq_name', your_last_number, true); --can use false in 3rd parameters
```

after that,  you can put a new value from the aplication